# Android c2dm 302 Http error

Tags: android, c++, qt, http, android-c2dm

everytime i want to send a push notification to my cell i get the 302 Moved Error from the Google servers. It says, it moved to www.google.com. This doesn't seem correct. So i have the following information:

- I am sitting behind a proxy, but i tried this also without a proxy. No effect.
- CUrl commandline method works fine
- Receiving the auth token from the Google servers works fine
- Changing the auth token i want to send has no real effect (changing the last 3-4 characters)
- Sending no registration id has no effect

Here is the code, that sends a push notification:

```
QString headerStr = QString("GoogleLogin auth=") + m_authCode;
qDebug(qPrintable(headerStr));

QUrl url;
url.addQueryItem("registration_id", m_pRegCode->text());
url.addQueryItem("collapse_key", "0");
url.addQueryItem("data.message", "data");
qDebug("%s", qPrintable(url.toString()));
qDebug("%s", qPrintable(QString(url.encodedQuery())));
QByteArray data;
data = url.encodedQuery();

QUrl header("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
QNetworkRequest req(header);
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, data.length());
req.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), headerStr.toAscii());

qDebug("%s", qPrintable(req.url().toString()));
m_pPushRep = m_pManager->post(req, data);
```

The answer i receive is:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit: The solution was actually pretty simple: I had a whitespace at the end of my authentication id. This actually led to the errorcode. So for everyone who reads this in the far future: CHECK YOUR AUTHENTICATION CODE!

Comment: Moved Temporary... It probably means that Google have maintenance.

Comment: This doesn't seem legit. It works fine with CUrl on the Commandline. So i assume that the Google servers are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. Worked from cURL but not from Qt. I however had to use the -k flag with cURL aka ignore ssl errors. After I did a simple ignoreSslErrors() on the QNetworkReply* it worked just fine for me, this might do the trick for you too. I now have this code to do the api call.

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send"));
QUrl postData;
postData.addQueryItem("collapse_key","1");
postData.addQueryItem("registration_id",id);
postData.addQueryItem("data.message",message);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, postData.encodedQuery().length());
request.setRawHeader("Authorization","GoogleLogin auth=....");
network->post(request,postData.encodedQuery())->ignoreSslErrors();
```

Which works just fine for me.